# Передать различные массивы данных во второй pickerView2 в зависимости от строки в первом PickerView1

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

Разобрался я как запрограммировать 2 pickerView в одном классе (см. ответ на вопрос).

Теперь хотелось бы понять, как менять массив данных во втором `pickerView2` в зависимости от выбранной стороки `row` в первом - есть один главный массив и 4 "зависимых". Надо при выборе нулевой строки (первой) в первом `pickerView1` выдавать один массив в `PickerView2`, первой (второй) в `PickerView1` выдавать второй в `pickerView2`,  и так еще два раза.

Пока как делать не знаю, но так подозреваю что за это отвечает функция  `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`, но как описать эти "процессы" я пока не понимаю. Буду признателен, если кто-то поможет разобраться.

Comment: Сложно понять, что именно вы хотите, но примерно могу Вам подсказать, выбираете строку в PikerView1, далее в зависимости от ваших нужд обновляете массив (datasource) Вашего PikerView2 и обновляете PikerView2 self.pickerView2l.reloadAllComponents(); Это основная идея, алгоритм реализации за Вами :)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!